# Custom select with radios

Tags: javascript, html, css

In some projects I have to use styled select dropdowns, there are lots of libraries to do that but they not working perfectly especially then there is some dynamic content.

I wanted to ask cos and pros for custom radio select:

HTML:

```
<div class="form_item f_select">
    <label class="current" for="select">Option #1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select" autocomplete="false" />

    <label for="select" class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li class="option">
                <input type="radio" name="select" id="option_1" value="value_1" />
                <label for="option_1">Option #1</label>
            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <input type="radio" name="select" id="option_2" value="value_2" />
                <label for="option_2">Option #2</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </label>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.f_select {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 13px;

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input {
        position: absolute;
        left: -99999px;
    }

    .current {
        border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
        padding: 2px 5px 1px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        display: inline-block;

        &:after {
            content: "▼";
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 9px;
            margin-left: 7px;
            position: relative;
            top: -1px;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        &:hover {
            border-color: #7e7e7e;
        }
    }
    input:checked + .dropdown {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    // IE8
    input.checked + .dropdown {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .dropdown {
        position: fixed;
        left: -9999px;
    }
    ul {
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #7f9db9;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 101;
    }
    li {
        line-height: 1.2;

        label:hover,
        input:checked + label {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #1e90ff;
        }

        // IE8
        label:hover,
        input.checked + label {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #1e90ff;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            padding: 0 5px 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And there is some javascript witch helps to work as native select.

Full code base is here: https://github.com/GomatoX/Select/

Thanks in future.

Comment: I personnally never like to override native controls with custom ones, although they're most of the time much nicer. There are many reasons for this including accessibility and OOB functionality that may (will) be broken with a "fake" control mimicking a native one, but most probably not all functionalities (e.g. : clicking the label focuses or check your control) and most probably the ones that may come with newer versions of browsers. That said, somtimes you don't have the choice as a developer, then the choice of a good substitute is important, but not a SO question.

Comment: I also love using native form items but sometimes it not depends on me. So i have to find "midle of gold" ( aphorism ). I see that most similar is radio inputs and i decided to write my own very simple select dropdown, (!) but I think there is some negatives of it, maby it's mobile devices. :/